# Vectors (finding magnitude)

Tags: vectors

$C$ and $D$ are points with position vectors $c$ and $d$ respectively. If the magnitude of $c=5$ and magnitude of $d=7$, and the dot product; $c\cdot d=4$. Find $|CD|$ (vector connecting $C$ and $D$)

I have tried $\cos \theta=\frac{4}{35}$
And substituted the angle into $a^2=7^2+5^2-2(7)(5)\cos \theta$ 
I got the wrong answer so i tried again but this time with $180-\theta$ for the angle but I still can't get an answer in exact form

Comment: Is $c.d$ the dot product? ($c\cdot d$)

Comment: yes it is the dot product of the 2 vectors

Comment: Dear miu: this question looks like a course assignment; you are more likely to invite positive reactions if you give some indication of what you have tried already, or what you know about the possible approach.

Comment: @miu Welcome to Maths SE.  __2__ things: Use [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1) to learn how to format via $\LaTeX$ and secondly, 
if someone gives an answer that is useful to you don't forget to tick it.  Your answer is `$\sqrt{66}$` which renders as $\sqrt{66}$. All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the dot product: 
$$
|\vec c| | \vec d|\cos \theta=\vec c \cdot \vec d
$$
where $\theta $ is the angle between the two vectors. Than use the [cosine rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines):

$$
\vec a=|CD|=\sqrt{|\vec c|^2+|\vec d|^2-2|c||d|\cos \theta}=\sqrt{|\vec c|^2+|\vec d|^2-2( \vec c \cdot \vec d)}=\sqrt{5^2+7^2-2(4)}=\sqrt{66}
$$

Comment: that is what i used but the answer was in exact form and it is $66^1/2$ (root 66 or 66 to the power of 1/2 but i cant seem to format it, sorry)

Comment: I've changed from an Hint to an answer. You can see the exact form.